# TypeError in Python 3 with the print function

Tags: python-3.x, string, typeerror

So I have been following this code and placed it in and it all seemed to be going well until the last line where I was printing the final string and a TypeError came up. Where is my mistake?

```
kingName = input("Yo King! Please type in your name at the prompt")
numJewels = input("Hey " + kingName + ", how many jewels are there?")
numJewels = int(numJewels)
costOfEachJewel = input("Yo " + kingName + ", how much does each jewel cost?")
costOfEachJewel = int(costOfEachJewel)
print (costOfEachJewel * numJewels)
dudeNames = ["Athos", "Pothos", "Aramis"]
dudeAges = [55,34, 67]
dudeNames.insert(0, "D'Artagnan")
print (dudeNames)
dudeAges.append(16)
print (dudeAges)
tempVariable = dudeNames.pop(0)
tempVariable
dudeNames.append(tempVariable)
print (dudeNames)
print (dudeAges)
print ("Total number of dudes: " + str(len(dudeNames)))
dudeToKill = input("Yo " + kingName + "please enter the # of the dude to kill")
print ("zapping all history of " + str(len(dudeNames[dudeToKill-1])))
```

Comment: Post the full stacktrace

Comment: `dudeToKill` is a string, what do you expect `dudeToKill - 1` to do?

Answer (score 0):

`dudeToKill` must be an `int`, convert the `input` to `int` before performing `dudeToKill - 1` operation.

```
dudeToKill = int(input("Yo " + kingName + "please enter the # of the dude to kill"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
kingName = input("Yo King! Please type in your name at the prompt")
numJewels = int(input("Hey " + kingName + ", how many jewels are there?"))
costOfEachJewel = int(input("Yo " + kingName + ", how much does each jewel cost?"))
print(costOfEachJewel * numJewels)
dudeNames = ["Athos", "Pothos", "Aramis"]
dudeAges = [55, 34, 67]
dudeNames.insert(0, "D'Artagnan")
print(dudeNames)
dudeAges.append(16)
print(dudeAges)
tempVariable = dudeNames.pop(0)
tempVariable
dudeNames.append(tempVariable)
print(dudeNames)
print(dudeAges)
print("Total number of dudes: " + str(len(dudeNames)))
dudeToKill = int(input("Yo " + kingName + "please enter the # of the dude to kill"))
print("zapping all history of " + str(len(dudeNames[dudeToKill-1])))
```

hope this will help

Comment: Always try to point out the OPs mistake. It is evident that he has done mistake in one line. He may not realize it if you don't mention it out clearly. Other comments are doing that!